# convert json response data into an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I want to convert JSON response data into an array. Pass the data using `json.stringify()` method and get the response in JSON format. But I want to convert this response into an array. My code is,

```
 $.ajax({
url: "url/json/Login",
type: "POST",
data: JSON.stringify({
    accountID: "ymmsansdu",
    userID: "ymmascnuelas",
    password: "ymma23@123"
}),
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function (data) {
    var response = JSON.stringify(data);
   alert(response);
},

});
```

The response of this code:

```
{"LoginResult":{"ErrorCode":0,"StatusMessage":"Success","UserInfo":{"AccountID":"dfdgfgh","Description"
:"description Cabs","EmailID":"","Name":"","PhoneNumber":"","UserID":"asxdsvdgfbg"}}}
```

I want to get `userInfo` into an array.

Please help me.

Comment: Pls read http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp

Comment: I'm tried, but JSON.parse(response) is showing [object Object].

Comment: @Arya The `alert()` is actually what's showing the `"[object Object]"` as it simply converts the value `.toString()`. And, that's the normal string form of an Object. This is in part why `alert()` isn't really the best tool for debugging. Try instead using `console.log(response)` and open the Console in your browser's developer tools to view the result.

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
**EDIT**

```
    var response = $.parseJSON(data);
    var arr = response.LoginResult;
    var userInfoArr = arr['UserInfo'];
```